# Bootstrap 5.3 - sass compiling doesn't work

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5, dart-sass

I hope you can help me.

To compile I use Dart Sass, I get the error:
*error node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss (Line 1107: $color: "var(--bs-success-rgb)" is not a color for `rgba')*
Does not recognize bootstrap variables.
I use the command: *sass --watch static/scss:static/css --style compressed --scss*

Compiling with Dart Sass works fine until I add bootstrap.scss and all its dependencies.

Thanks to anyone who can help me

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this issue? - chances are your Sass compiler is out of date for the latest changes.  I've been experiencing the problem with Web Compiler 2017 with VS.  Having upgraded to VS2022 with the new Sass compiler the error no longer shows.  In short ,check for an update.